# Chrome Web Developer Tools Shortcut for hover state

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Is there a keyboard shortcut to enable hover state in Chrome Web Dev Tools without going through the icon?

Answer (score 2):

All DT shortcuts are written down in the `Settings -> Shortucts` (to open DT settings click on the cog icon in the lower right corner of DT window) and in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/shortcuts). There is no shortcut for `Force element state -> :hover` if that's what you are thinking about.